# Reduce bundle size of @vue and vuetify/lib

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vite, vuetifyjs3

I'm having a vue 3.2.45 app with vite 4.0.4 and vuetify 3.1.4 installed. I used the `rollup-plugin-visualizer` to analyze the bundle size and it turns out that the node_modules directory is about 900 kB (245 kB gzipped) large. Is there any way to decrease that size? Especially the `@vue` bundle seems to be large, although I have no special configuration.

Also, the `vuetify/lib` directory seems to include every vuetify component, although I'm having treeshaking included via `vite-plugin-vuetify` (v1.0.1) and it seems to work in the `src` directory, but not inside the `node_modules`. I'm not sure if that is the expected behavior.

My `vite.config.ts` looks like this:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'url'

import type { PluginOption } from 'vite'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { version } from './package.json'
import vuetify from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'
import VueI18nPlugin from '@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n/vite'
import { dirname, resolve } from 'node:path'
import { visualizer } from 'rollup-plugin-visualizer'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: './',
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        compilerOptions: {
          isCustomElement: (tag) => tag.includes('xx-'),
        },
      },
    }),
    vuetify(),
    // https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/optimization.html#unplugin-vue-i18n
    VueI18nPlugin({
      /* options */
      // locale messages resource pre-compile option
      include: resolve(dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)), './locales/**'),
    }),
    visualizer({
      template: 'treemap', // or sunburst
      open: true,
      gzipSize: true,
      brotliSize: true,
    }) as PluginOption,
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        entryFileNames: `something.js`,
        chunkFileNames: `something.js`,
        assetFileNames: `assets/something.[ext]`,
      },
    },
  },
})
```

I included vuetify via the following code (styles are excluded already since tree shaking is not working for vuetify.scss, it's imported manually in every component instead):

vuetify.ts:

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'

// https://vuetifyjs.com/en/introduction/why-vuetify/#feature-guides
export default createVuetify()
```

main.ts

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'

import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify'
import VueDOMPurifyHTML from 'vue-dompurify-html'

const app = createApp(App)

const pinia = createPinia()
app.use(pinia)
app.use(vuetify)
app.use(VueDOMPurifyHTML)

app.mount('#app')
```

[image: node_modules bundle size analyzed by rollup visualizer]

Comment: Note that the sizes reported by rollup-plugin-visualizer are [not reliable](https://github.com/btd/rollup-plugin-visualizer/issues/96), the tool is rather about what is in a package instead of its size. In my project, the sizes reported by the plugin is up to three times the actual size of the file on disk. Where does your size of 900 kB (245 kB gzipped) come from? Because from the size of Vue itself, I would guess you get a package of around 400 kB unzipped.

Comment: that's a good point! but for me the size that is shown by rollup-plugin-visualizer and the actual file size of the js file inside the dist directory match more or less. At least it's a first indicator, I'll investigate it more though.

Comment: The 900 kB are mainly coming from "vuetify/lib" with 300 kB and "@vue" with around 250 kB. Axios, marked.js and dompurify.js taking up another 250 kB all together.

Comment: When the sizes reported by the visualizer matches the output, I think it means that your files are not minified. Does the output look minified? You could try setting [build.minify](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-minify) in vite config

Comment: build.minify should be the default, right?

Comment: Yes, it is. Is it working though, are your files minified?

Comment: yes, they are, seems to work fine